# Trying to run VMWare on Xubuntu Desktop 16.04 (Kernel Header Missing Error)

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, vmware-workstation

*My goal: To successfully run VMware on my Xubuntu Desktop 16.04.*

My problem: After almost completing the entire installation of 'VMware-Workstation-Full-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle'I can't get past the following error.

Find below the cmd line instructions I used to install VMware (used a tutorial online)

```
# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
# chmod a+x VMware-Workstation-Full-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle
# sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-12.5.6-5528349.x86_64.bundle
```

After these steps, I wrote the 'vmware' command which gave me the following error:

> GCC
>
> GNU C Compiler (gcc) version 6.3.0 was not found. If you installed
> it in a non-default path you can specify the path below. Otherwise
> refer to your distribution's documentation for installation
> instructors and click Refresh to search again in default locations.

In order to resolve this error, I manually installed the correct version required (6.3.0). After this error is where I have been stuck for a long time. This is the error I received after:

> Error: C header files matching your running kernel were not found.
> Refer to your distributions documents for instattion instructions.

After pressing "ok" here is the detailed error message:

> Kernel Headers 4.9.33-mod-std-ipv6-64
>
> Kernel headers for version 4.9.33-mod-std-ipv6-64 were not found. If you installed them in a non-default path you can specify the path below. Otherwise refer to
> your distribution's documentation for installation instructions and
> click Refresh to search again in default locations.

Also, I checked to see the Kernel headers installed in my system under /usr/srs -

linux-headers-4.4.0-87

linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic

linux-headers-4.4.0-97

linux-headers-4.4.0-97- generic

This was the output to cmd 'uname -r'

4.9.33-mod-std-ipv6-64

Comment: It *sounds* like it's looking for a specific kernel version, 4.9.33 or later.  Problem is your system isn't running 4.9 kernels, so that won't work very well.  Did you download the right VMware bundle?>

Comment: Have you done `sudo apt install build essential` yet?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I downloaded 12.5.6-5528349.x86_64. Prior to that I downloaded 12.1.1 and I faced the same issue! @ThomasWard

Comment: @MoeChong I'd reach out to VMware and ask them if they have a version that works with the older kernel on your system.  It's entirely possible they want a newer kernel than you actually have, which will cause some headaches.   But here's a question: are you running a newer kernel?  Because it suggests that you have a newer kernel than you're actually running.  Include the output of `uname -r` as an edit to your question.

Comment: When I try using sudo apt install build essential, I get the following error. E: Unable to locate package build. E: Unable to locate package essential @CharlesGreen

Comment: @MoeChong `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.  But answer my part please, I need to know what kernel you're running, because it probably doesn't match what's installed.

Comment: I added the required information to the question as requested. Sorry for the slight delay! @ThomasWard

Comment: After running sudo apt-get install build-essential, I get the following output. sh-4.3$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: @MoeChong Look at the kernel versions you have installed from apt, and such, and compare those numbers to the `uname -r` output.  Then read my answer.  You've got an odd system where you have a newer kernel (possibly customized) than ships with standard Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this on an OVH server or dedicated system from OVH/Kimsufi?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two sets of issues.

First is your `gcc` version.  I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and even the VMware Workstation 14 Pro installer works fine with standard `gcc`.  I do not know why it's demanding `gcc` >= 6.0.

Your second problem is your kernel.  You are running a ***far newer kernel than you have installed from the repositories***.  That is why you won't find the headers anywhere.  It's possible you're using a custom compiled kernel or a system which has had a custom kernel installed on it.  In both cases, you should probably reconsider the use of this newer 4.9-based kernel and go back to the original kernels that ship with the Ubuntu repositories.  Otherwise, you need to have a copy of the kernel headers for your custom built kernel on-system and point VMware towards that.

The first `gcc` version issue is probably related to the second and what was used to compile that kernel, but I can't be certain.  I do know though that your kernel is far too new for what ships with Ubuntu, and the chances that you'll have the sources and headers for that are low unless you did a custom compile yourself.